# How to handle questions on buying ETH?

Tags: discussion

As an example: [How do I buy Ethereum with USD?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/how-do-i-buy-ethereum-with-usd)

These kind of questions could be a potential source of all kinds of spam, fake/scam site or affiliate links posts.

On the other hand to mark them as off topic isn't solving the demand either. To do anything with Ethereum you need ETH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about we protect the question, so that people need at least 10 rep to answer?  Then deal with it again if the problem persists with that small hurdle?  Would be interested in other answers about how other SE deal with related issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, preemptively protecting a question to keep newer users from answering would not be appropriate  (and soon will not be allowed until an actual problem has been demonstrated — [Prevent protecting questions under certain circumstances](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances)). If the question isn't actually attracting a lot of low-quality answers from drive-by users, protection was never intended to be used in this manner.

Comment: I agree and wasn't suggesting preemptive protection; the example question did have pretty good answers already, and forgot to mention it above :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what eth said, we could merge them all to one canonical question about buying and selling Ether. I don't think we need seprate questions for each currency exchange. This would keep this clean and simple and easy to maintain.

Edit, I just had to protect one more question:

- [Where can I buy Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/148/87)